# validate start and end time for dynamically added input fields in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation, timepicker

[I have made a JSFIDDLE link for reference here.](https://jsfiddle.net/arneh1Lt/10/) The validation for start and end time starts on the click of the 'Next' button, which is on the same page. I want to validate the start and end time for dynamically created fields as -> Start time should be smaller than the end time. I have created an array and then checked for time using the if loops. I have pasted the code below here. But the validation fails when the start time selected is 8:30am and end time as 10.00am. I am not able to understand why this is happening. Please help.

```
<td data-name="sub_event_stime[]" >

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter time" name="sub_event_stime[]" class="span11 timepicker sub_event_stime" style="background-color: #FFF;margin-top: 3%;height: 37px;width: 69%;text-align: center;">                       
<br/>    
</td>

<td data-name="sub_event_etime[]" >


<input type="text" name="sub_event_etime[]"  placeholder="Enter time" class="span11 timepicker sub_event_etime" style="background-color: #FFF;margin-top: 3%;height: 37px;width: 69%;text-align: center;">

<br/>    

</td>

<td data-name="sub_event_venue[]" >

<input type="text" name='sub_event_venue[]'  
placeholder='Venue' class="form-control sub_event_venue" style="text-
align:center;margin-left:16%;margin-top:10px;height: 29px;width: 
68.4%;padding:17px;   "/>

</td>
```

Jquery code

```
$('#next_button').click(function(e) {

     var stime = [];
     $.each($('.sub_event_stime'), function (i, item) 
     {
        var val = $(this).val(); 
        stime.push( val );
     });

     var etime = [];
     $.each($('.sub_event_etime'), function (i, item) 
     {
        var val = $(this).val(); 
        etime.push( val );

     });


     var venue = [];
     $.each($('.sub_event_venue'), function (i, item) 
     {
        var val = $(this).val(); 
        venue.push( val );

     });

        for(var i=0; i < venue.length; i++) 
        {
            for(var j=i+1; j < venue.length; j++) 
            {
                if(venue[i] == venue[j] && venue[i] !=  "" && venue[j] != "" && stime[i] == stime[j] && etime[i] != "" && etime[j] != "" && stime[i]!= '' )
                {

                    console.log(venue);
                    console.log(stime);
                    console.log(etime);

                    $('.sub_event_stime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_etime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_venue').eq(j).val('');
                    alert("Same time and same venue not allowed");
                    $(this).attr('type','submit');
                    return false;

                }
                else if(stime[i] > etime[i] && stime[i] != '' && etime[i] !== '')
                {

                    console.log(venue);
                    console.log(stime);
                    console.log(etime);

                    $('.sub_event_stime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_etime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_venue').eq(j).val('');
                    alert("Start time should be smaller than end time"); 
                    $(this).attr('type','submit');
                    return false;   
                } 
                else if((stime[i] == etime[i]) && (stime[j] == '' ) && (etime[j] == ''))
                {

                    console.log(venue);
                    console.log(stime);
                    console.log(etime);

                    $('.sub_event_stime').eq(i).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_etime').eq(i).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_venue').eq(i).val('');

                    alert("Start time and end time cannot be same"); 
                    $(this).attr('type','submit');
                    return false;   
                }
                else if((stime[j] == etime[j]) && (stime[i] == '') && (etime[i] == ''))
                {

                    console.log(venue);
                    console.log(stime);
                    console.log(etime);

                    $('.sub_event_stime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_etime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_venue').eq(j).val('');
                    alert("Start time and end time cannot be same"); 
                    $(this).attr('type','submit');
                    return false;   
                }
                else if(etime[j] < etime[i] && venue[i] == venue[j] && etime[j] != '' && etime[i] != '')
                {

                    console.log(venue);
                    console.log(stime);
                    console.log(etime);

                    $('.sub_event_stime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_etime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_venue').eq(j).val('');
                    alert("This range has already been used");  
                    $(this).attr('type','submit');
                    return false;   
                }
                else if(stime[j] > stime[i] && venue[i] == venue[j] && stime[j] != '' && stime[i] != '')
                {
                    console.log(venue);
                    console.log(stime);
                    console.log(etime);

                    $('.sub_event_stime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_etime').eq(j).val('');
                    $('.sub_event_venue').eq(j).val('');
                    alert("This range has already been used");  
                    $(this).attr('type','submit');
                    return false;

                }



            }
        }




});
```

Comment: can you please provide the complete necessary html ? Most of the selectors used in your JQuery code are missing

Comment: ok..will edit..now

Comment: Even better if you could provide us with a Fiddle or so replicating the issue. Faster problem solving for both of us

Comment: hi..i have added a JS fiddle link also..

Comment: Selecting start time as `8:30am` and end time as `10:00am` is correct, isn't it? Start time is actually smaller than end time. Why would you expect an error in this case

Comment: yes it is correct, still the alert appears..hence validation is not taking place correctly..

Comment: Hmm .. the alert doesn't seem to appear to me for these times. Can you check in the Fiddle ?

Comment: I have updated the JS fiddle link..please open again..sorry for trouble.

Comment: am I missing something or are you actually comparing `strings` with bigger-than (>) and smaller-than (<) operators ?

Comment: I m newbie in jquery..and since i felt it was working..i continued with it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue here:

```
 (etime[j] < etime[i] && venue[i] == venue[j] && etime[j] != '' && etime[i] != '')
```

these are all strings. which should not be compared using < > operators.

out of [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

> When comparing two strings, "2" will be greater than "12", because
>   (alphabetically) 1 is less than 2.
>
> An empty string converts to 0 while A non-numeric string converts to NaN
>   which is always false.
>
> To secure a proper result, variables should be converted to the proper
>   type before comparison.

Comment: please suggest how am i supposed to compare them?

Comment: hey, you should convert your time string, to a Date object. if you google it there are many examples out there

Comment: @Unnati exactly.

Comment: @Unnati if this answer resolved your issue please mark it as resolved to wrap it up

Comment: please check this https://jsfiddle.net/arneh1Lt/14/ , I have used the Date.parseExact function, but it seems the values are not entering inside the stime array. Please help